# JQuery .focus() event changing DropDown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, telerik

I have a selectlist with that is built using jquery inside a grid. When a user enters a key the select list is built, I then call click() and focus() so that I can use the key commands again.

The problem that I have is that .focus() is changing the selection of the select list when fired when it is fired. Has anyone experienced this behaviour before or found a workaround? Thanks in advance

```
function INTEREST_createPaymentTypeDropDown() {
    //Interest specific:
    //build a dropdown for the enum
    //if the PaymentType input exists
    if ($("#PaymentType").length > 0) {

        var cellPaymentTypeValue = $("#PaymentType").val();
        var selectedOption;

        $("#PaymentType").replaceWith("<select id='PaymentType' style='width:95px; height: 20px;' name='PaymentType'></select>");
        $.each(INTEREST_PAYMENT_TYPES, function(key, val) {
            var newoption = $("<option value=\"" + val + "\">" + key + "</option>");

            if (val == cellPaymentTypeValue || key == cellPaymentTypeValue) {
                //append select to the current value
                selectedOption = val;
            }
            $("#PaymentType").append(newoption);
            $("#PaymentType").addClass("t-input");
        });

        if (selectedOption != null) {
            $("#PaymentType").val(selectedOption.toString());
        }
    }


    function INTEREST_setEditField(field) {
        if ($("#PaymentType").length > 0) {
            // this is where the problem is
            $("#PaymentType").click();
        }
        else {
            $(".t-grid-content").find('.t-input').click();
            $(".t-grid-content").find('.t-input').select();
        }

        INTEREST_persistPaymentTypeOnCellChange(field);
    }

    function INTEREST_persistPaymentTypeOnCellChange(field) {
        //keep the value of the enum not the enum index
        //in the payment type field
        var paymentTypeCell = $(field).parent().children().eq(1);

        if ($(paymentTypeCell).html().length == 1) {
            $.each(INTEREST_PAYMENT_TYPES, function(key, val) {
                if ($(paymentTypeCell).html() == val) {
                    $(paymentTypeCell).html(key);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $('td.t-grid-edit-cell', 'div#AccountPayments').live('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.which == 39 || event.which == 9) //Tab or right arrow
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('t-last')) {
                INTEREST_goToNextRow(this, event);
            }
            else {
                INTEREST_goToRight(this, event);
            }
        }
        else if (event.which == 37 || event.which == 9 && event.shiftKey) //left arrow. Todo: add shift tab
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('t-first')) {
                INTEREST_goToPreviousRow(this, event);
            }
            else {
                INTEREST_goToLeft(this, event);
            }
        }
        else if (event.which == 40) //down arrow
        {
            INTEREST_goDown(this, event);
        }
        else if (event.which == 38) //up arrow
        {
            INTEREST_goUp(this, event);
        }
    });

    $("#PaymentType").live('click', function(event) {
        $(this).focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there's no empty option at the top of the list so that when the `click()` is called it's causing `PaymentType` to auto-select the 0th option?

Comment: Hi there is empty option and but it would default to the first option rather than the second. When I the drop down from the right or bottom it changes it from the first to the second, and if I enter from the the top it changes it to the second value.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this line?

`if (val == cellPaymentTypeValue || key == cellPaymentTypeValue) {
                //append select to the current value
                selectedOption = val;
            }
`

Why would the code compare the `key` and the `val` to the same variable?  Are they the same?

Comment: Also, could the `focus()` call be sending an event code that you're not necessarily expecting and triggering the `keydown` event or another function?  Also, I assume there's no special behavior/function defined for the `focus()` function.

These are kind of shooting in the dark, so I'm sorry if it's not helpful.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for the response. The reason I compare, both key and val to the my variable is that it is possible that the value in the cell could be either a string or an integer. I'm pretty sure you're right about focus, it seems to go off and call other events which in turn call focus again and this changes the selectlist selected index

Comment: Something strange happened with `focus` before to me, too.  I was setting `focus` and it wasn't putting the cursor in the field, but the field actually did have focus.

I solved it by first blurring the field and then focusing the field.  You might try that to see if it helps at all???